# General solution for a program's exit status with set -e

Tags: bash, exit-code

I am programming in Bash now and I use `set -e` because to continue the script when a program has failed is hardly the wanted behavior.

When it is I use `||true` if I do not need the exit code.

If I need the exit code I wrap the execution like this:

```
set +e
call_I_need_the_exit_code with few arguments
RV="$?"
set -e
# use "$RV" somewhat
```

However, it is verbose and I seldom switch `set +e` and `set -e` introducing annoying bugs.

Is there a way to make a function that executes the command and setup a known variable to the exit code?

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
safe_call( call_I_need_the_exit_code(with, few, arguments) )
# use "$RV" somewhat
```

where `safe_call` basically does the previous block of code. It would make my code easier to write and read...

Comment: Apparently "The shell stores the exit value of most recently executed command in the variable '?' "

Comment: Your latest edit doesn't really make sense. In particular, `A="es"` is simply a string assignment which doesn't call the function `es`; and you need a newline or semicolon before the closing braces. Your question should remain strictly a question anyhow. Please consider rolling back this edit; feel free to post an answer of your own if you genuinely think mine isn't understandable (or submit an edit suggestion if you'd like to clarify something).

Comment: really strange, I copy and pasted a file where I definitely have the backticks there! Edit: backticks need the backslash.

Comment: Still, the question should be *only* a question. You can submit an answer of your own in the answer box below if you like; but your question should not be edited to include answers or tangential commentary. See further the [help] or if you need further clarificatiens on Stack Overflow policy, post a separate question on [meta].

Comment: I rolled back your recent edits. They are still visible in the [revision history](/posts/51205440/revisions) if you would like to post the content as an answer.

Comment: Rollback as much as you want. I got my answer. If removing the example helps in any way, just do it. I admit I do not really get this.

Comment: I can't quickly find a good Meta post about this, though this one touches on vaguely the same topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296040/change-question-title-because-of-answer - again, if you think this policy needs further discussion or clarification, please bring it up in a separate question on Meta rather than down here in the comments where it's really just you and me.

Comment: Also this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason `|| true` works is that conditionals are safe under `set -e`. This can be extended easily to your scenario.

```
command && rv=0 || rv=$?
```

As an aside, you should [avoid uppercase for your private variables.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/are-there-naming-conventions-for-variables-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: The first version of this answer tried to wrap this in a function, but that obviously *isn't* safe under `set -e`; sorry about that.

Comment: Good thinking, obvious in hindsight as I like it. 

Alternatives may be: `&&rv=$?||rv=$?` (to allow mindless writing) or `rv=0` earlier and just `||rv=$?`.

About the caps, I did not write the code conventions here... and honestly I kinda like the variables as well different than shell commands.Anyhow, thanks for pointing me to the Google's Shell Style Guide as it will definitely be a good read.